# Monitor disk activity programmatically (Windows)

Tags: .net, windows, wmi, performancecounter

In Windows 2008R2, in Resource Monitor in the Disk Activity section I can see the number of bytes read from/written into files. How can I do this in a programmatic manner, preferably using C# (or Win32 API)? I have looked into WMI and various performance counters, however I cannot figure out if there is something which suits my needs.

Answer (score 2):

The counters relating to file I/O are on the `LogicalDisk` and `PhysicalDisk` objects. Take a look in Perfmon to see what counters are available.

Use the [PerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) class in C# or the [PDH API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373214(VS.85).aspx) in C/C++. In my experience these are much more efficient than WMI - though this may not matter in your application.

Comment: Though, if anyone knows how to get a per-file breakdown of IO stats (as in resmon) I would also be interested.

Comment: Anyone found a way in these 6 years to get the per-file breakdown?